# Get List Title of a search result item

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to get the the display title of the list, related to search result item in SharePoint search.

Result have OriginalPath and ParentLink values. But those are links to the list with internal name. But i could not find either display title or GUID of the list.

Please let me know how get either display title or GUID of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SharePoint REST service to get the search results in a XML format which return all the fields and their values.

Querying with the Search REST service - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/office/jj163876.aspx

You can construct the GET request URL with the query parameters as follows:

> http://server/_api/search/query?query_parameter=value&query_parameter=value

The SharePoint 2013 Search Query Tool is a handy tool to quickly get the search results in XML format - https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/

Comment: Those does not return list title.

Answer (score 0):

Found this [post](http://www.eliostruyf.com/retrieving-list-library-name-search-result-display-templates/) which describes how to get the list title of a search result item in a display template.

Since there is no managed property which contains the list title by default, the display template adds the list title to each item by retrieving it via a REST call using the web URL and the list ID.

- https://github.com/SPCSR/DisplayTemplates/tree/master/Search%20Display%20Templates/Retrieve%20the%20list%20name%20in%20a%20display%20template